# in Safari, jquery not found when query.min.js is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I have a simple HTML page which calls `jquery.min.js`

The JavaScript (which includes jQuery functions) on the page runs fine.

However, if I look at Safari's Web Inspector Console, the following error is reported:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery-1.10.2.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

If I create an un-minified version of jQuery and save it as `jquery-1.10.2.js`, then the error message goes away.

Does jquery.min.js require the un-minified version of jQuery to reside in the same folder?

**Update**

Here is the HTML in its entirety.  As you can see it is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Homepage</title>
        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $ (document).ready(function() {
                $('body').css('background-color', '#f00');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>hello world</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"Does jquery.min.js require the un-minified version of jQuery to reside in the same folder?"_ No. If the console shows a 404 for `jquery-1.10.2.js` then it's looking for a file with that name, not `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: Okay thanks.  Why would calling jquery.min.js make the browser call for jquery-1.10.2.js?

Comment: It shouldn't. Got a link for us to look at?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load

```
http://www.mydomain.com/js/jquery-1.10.2.js
```

somewhere in your project. Search for `jquery-1.10.2.js` in your root folder and modify all the occurrences to valid paths.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a "feature" of Safari but I could not find any reference to it in the documentation. If it cannot find the unminified version of .js file, it will beautify to make it easier to debug. It is similar how Chrome checks for the .map file of a minified JavaScript file but Safari goes further and tries to load the same file without the ".min" part.

Apparently there is no way to disable this feature, at least we could not find one.